# How move parameter location in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to move the parameter 'TableName' from the bottom to the top i.e above 'CountName'. I thought it simply a matter of dragging it from its existing location to where you would like. In the image you can see I have the cross-hairs that enable me to drag the Parameter TableName but when I drag and release the Parameter remains at the bottom.

[image]

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

I have updated the image with move arrows, see below
[image]

I have added another image showing the actual move arrows, see below

[image]

Comment: I Tried to reproduce, but I don't see the move arrows in your screenshot, nor the import button. Anyhow, I think the only way to re-order is to delete all parameters and start over.

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, I have updated my image with the move cross-hairs. I can't believe it's not possible

Comment: Added another showing actual move arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the above scenario, and it is same for me.

[image]

**AFAIK**, It might not be possible to move the parameters. Either you need to delete all parameters and create by your order or rename the parameter names, types and values might be the workaround as suggested in comments.

(OR)

You can edit the parameters in the pipeline JSON as per your requirement.

[image]

The parameters which are needed for the stored procedure can be created by clicking on **import** button in it and these will be created in the order of the stored procedure. The stored procedure will identify the parameters by the name of the parameter.

If you want to change the order, you need to edit your stored procedure or edit the parameters like above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure updating the JSON is the only way to reorder the parameters. This also works for Pipeline parameters and Variables.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh can you let me know what you used to produce your gif? I really like it

Comment: 'ScreentoGif' - you need to download it.